# Name of 16 pin male connector

Tags: connector, pins

I searched everywhere, but I don't know how to describe this black connector for google query. This connector has 16 pins.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: >  I don't know how to describe -- Blind-mate board-to-board connector, straight, blade, 16 circuits.

Comment: @pipe. I edited the question: 16 pin, not 26.

Comment: @peter. Is it for a battery? What is it used for? Do you have pictures of its mate? If not, do you know anything about its mate? Do the blades retract if you push them down?

Comment: This is directly form this device: https://shop.delfi.com/da/vare/delfi-nova-single-slot-cradle-usb-rs232/ But I have connector from other charging station, SKORPIOX3

Comment: I think these pins are *spring-loaded*, so another term to include in your search. But honestly: it's not that unlikely that the connector is a custom design for the specific device class you're dealing with.

Comment: Can’t see any on your pictures, but are there any markings?

Comment: google `16 pin cradle connector` ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=16+pin+cradle+connector&iax=images&ia=images